# Trying to use command ./vendor/bin/sail up, does not work

Tags: windows, laravel-8

i'm creating laravel 8 project, where documentation says, from project root folder i should use

```
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

however, this happens

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app>./vendor/bin/sail up
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i don't understand, how `dot` is not a current path. i went over this [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them), but i couldn't find if i need to specify `dot` as `currentpath`.

furthermore, according to [this](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1envvars.htm) i'm not even sure `currentpath` needs to be specified and in my `system environment variables` i didn't find anything that could override default settings.

what am i missing?

Comment: I'd say on Windows you'd have to use: `.\vendor\bin\sail up`

Comment: `C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app>.\vendor\bin\sail up
/bin/bash: C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\vendor\bin\/../laravel/sail/bin/sail: No such file or directory` still no luck but i think its a progress